# Cannot get response from C# API controller with Angular

Tags: c#, .net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm getting started with Angular and I've created a C# (.NET 6) and Angular (14.1.2) application. And there is trouble with accessing my controller: I can't get a response from HTTP methods of my controller.

Interesting that the default 'WeatherForecastController', which is being created with a new project, works fine.

### Controller:

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ProductController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/<ProductController>
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getnumb")]
        public int GetNumber()
        {
            return 43;
        }
    }
```

### Program.cs

```cs
using Hardware_Store_App.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
}));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("corsapp");

app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

app.Run();
```

Error that appears in the browser's console when I'm trying to request the controller's method:

```
core.mjs:6485 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'api/product'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'api/product'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.mjs:2939:16)
    at router.mjs:2921:28
    at catchError.js:10:38
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (OperatorSubscriber.js:23:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:40:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:64:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:40:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:64:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:40:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:64:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165:1)
    at zone.js:1278:1
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25579:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:585:1)
```

[Here's what Postman returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3HYe.png)

So I assume, maybe I have to declare controller or something

Comment: How do you have your `Program.cs` file? you might need to call `MapControllers`.

Comment: We need more code, as Mihail requests

Comment: @MihailBrinza, I've added Program.cs file's code.

Comment: Maybe i wrong, but you need slash at the end of url(that worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

Use just `app.MapControllers();`

Like so:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

And make your method like this

```
    [HttpGet("getnumb")]
    public int GetNumber()
    {
        return 43;
    }
```

Comment: I did it, but still, it doesn't work.

Comment: Please see my updated response for MapControllers(). That should resolve it.

Comment: If this does not, can you post the URL you are trying to reach? Also can you verify the port and everything is correct also?

Comment: Yeah, the problem was the wrong port, thanks.

Comment: Awesome happy to hear. Perhaps mark this as correct so it will close out the request. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having:

```cs
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Use:

```cs
app.MapControllers();
```

This way .NET will look for all Controllers in your application and map them :)

Edit:
You can also add `swagger` to more easily debug these situations:

```cs
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// ... other services

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

Comment: I did like you said, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: try to add swagger, as indicated in the answer. Maybe you are not accessing the right `port`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the wrong port, I've been trying to request. I thought the server runs on the port, that opens by default in the browser. But I don't have a clue why it worked fine with the default controller...